# Data Type Mismatch Error Even Though Data Types Are the Same

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a "run time error 13:  Type mismatch" in the code below?  Both the cell2 and lookupvalues variables are variant data types, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
Sub MULTVLOOKUP()

    Dim lookupvalues As Variant
    Dim lookuprange As Range
    Dim returnrange As Range
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim cell2 As Variant

    lookupvalues = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What value do you want to      search for?", Title:="lookupvalue", Type:=8)
    Set lookuprange = Application.InputBox("What range do you want to search for this value in?", "lookuprange", Type:=8)
    Set returnrange = Application.InputBox("What cell do you want the results to begin being returned at?", "returnrange", Type:=8)

    For Each cell In lookupvalues
        For Each cell2 In lookuprange
            If InStr(1, cell2, lookupvalues) > 0 Then
                returnrange = cell2
                Set returnrange = returnrange.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Just FYI, I want this macro to return cell values from a range the user defines (lookuprange) that meet one of multiple criteria that the user also defines (lookupvalues).  The applicable cell values would then be returned starting on at a range the user defines (returnrange).  All of these user inputs are done through input boxes.  I've already gotten the macro to work when the user only selects one criteria, but I've been trying to modify the code so that multiple criteria/cells can be chosen.  The error is occurring on this line:

```
If InStr(1, cell2, lookupvalues) > 0 Then
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: is lookupvalues a range or a variant? You are treating it as both. My guess is it is a range and need to be changed to such.

Comment: `If InStr(1, cell2, cell) > 0 Then` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments this is my best guess as to what you are trying

```
Sub MULTVLOOKUP()

    Dim lookupvalues As Range
    Dim lookuprange As Range
    Dim returnrange As Range
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim cell2 As Variant

    Set lookupvalues = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What value do you want to      search for?", Title:="lookupvalue", Type:=8)
    Set lookuprange = Application.InputBox("What range do you want to search for this value in?", "lookuprange", Type:=8)
    Set returnrange = Application.InputBox("What cell do you want the results to begin being returned at?", "returnrange", Type:=8)

    For Each cell In lookupvalues
        For Each cell2 In lookuprange
            If InStr(1, cell2, cell.Value) > 0 Then
                returnrange = cell2
                Set returnrange = returnrange.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @christopheralan88 Feedback is always helpful.  Did this help? If not what does not work for you?  If it did consider marking as correct.